# Modulus: [Error] There was an error uploading. Meteor App

Tags: meteor, upload, modulus

So I'm trying to deploy a Meteor app using modulus
all go good, until upload give me that error

```
 Compressing project...
26.9 MB written
Uploading project...
Upload progress [=====              ] 28%{}

[Error] There was an error uploading.
```

Thanks for answering me ASAP.

Comment: Same Here. I have already discussed this issue with Modulus.io team to no avail. It seems like I will have to move out of Modulus.

Answer (score 0):

I guess i've solved it, I've changed my project from Meteor to nodeJS, then update npm & modulus in my computer, and rerun the modulus deploy, or simply try zipping you project and uploaded it manually from modulus.io